# Attaching a .png file to an email sent by satchmo

Tags: django, satchmo

In a Satchmo Store, I need to attach a small .png (a barcode) to an email that django sends on completion of the order. The email is formatted in HTML using send_order_confirmation() which calls send_store_mail() (both part of satchmo.) Neither of these functions offer the ability to attach a file (I think) so should I just re-write them? I was wondering if it is possible/better to do this using signals. Maybe rendering_store_mail() ?

By the way, the barcode would be dynamically generated, so there's no way of having a link to a file on a server somewhere.

Many thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

well I too had to add extra infos to the confirmation emails, only text though. So this would be the very easy way to add extra-stuff to emails using signals, which IMHO, is the best approach to do it. Always use signals if you can avoid overriding the satchmo-core ;-)

1. define your listener to add some context for the rendering. In this case I'm adding the contents of an extra notes field, and the barcode for this order, supposing there is a function named `get_barcode_img(<order>)`, to the context. I'm supposing here too, that the `get_barcode_img` function would return not just a png, but something like a MIMEImage (like `from email.MIMEImage import MIMEImage`) to be able to just include it inline. Also, there might be more infos needed, like a MIME-header for the img.

   ```
   # localsite/payment/listeners.py

   def add_extra_context_to_store_mail(sender,
           send_mail_args={}, context={}, **kwargs):
       if not 'order' in context:
           return
       context['barcode_header'] = get_barcode_header(context['order'])
       context['barcode_img'] = get_barcode_img(context['order'])
       context['notes'] = context['order'].notes
   ```
2. connect the listener to the signal somewhere where the code will be "discovered" for sure, like `models.py`:

   ```
   # localsite/payment/models.py 

   from satchmo_store.shop.signals import rendering_store_mail, order_notice_sender

   rendering_store_mail.connect(payment_listeners.add_extra_context_to_store_mail, sender=order_notice_sender)
   ```
3. override the templates locally (e.g. `order_placed_notice.html`) to add the new context. Be aware where you put your templates, as the path is essential for django to take your new template instead of the satchmo's one. In this case, starting from your project's root-path, there could be a templates-folder and inside it, there must be exactly the same path as in the satchmo-folder. E.g. /templates/shop/email/order_placed_notice.html  ... this can be applied for any "valid" templates-folder inside an app. It's up to you to decide, where/how the templates should be organized.

   ```
   <!-- templates/shop/email/order_placed_notice.html -->
   <!DOCTYPE ...><html>
   <head>
       <!-- include the image-header here somewhere??? -->
       <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>        
   ...
   Your comments:
   {{ notes }}

   Barcode:
   {{ barcode_img }}"
   ```